# How do I download a copy of the art that appears when I click a card in the "[Account] earned a trading card" of a game's Library page?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

How do I download a copy of the art that appears when, in the Steam client, I click a card in the "[Account] earned a trading card" section of a Library page for a game?

And it seems if I've earned a card too far in the past, I can't see the image anymore, and that only that section of the client reveals an image.

[image]

Mouseover

[image: Mouseover]

Click

[image: Click]

Not sure how steamcardexchange managed to find the URLs for all the images, when they click on them.

https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?gamepage-appid-960690

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot of the "[Account] earned a trading card" section? I am not sure what you mean by that or where to find it.

Comment: @Madjura - How's that? Also found out that steamcardexchange can get the pictures too.

Answer (score 3):

On chrome:
Left click on the image, inspect element: There should be something with a background image closeby. Its the image you are looking for.

Here is the URL for the image you talked about. https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/960690/db70016d6b4eb82fb30fa7a33f4fa202ef2b36da.jpg

[image]

Other solution, CTRL+S will save the page locally, with everything related to it. The image you are looking for should be in all those files.

But yeah, uf you are looking for an automated way to get the image, I would guess the [Steam Open API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev) has what you are looking for. I just don't know enough to guide you in it.

Comment: Whoops, I know how HTML works, so I know *where* the steamcardexchange images links are, just not how they find them to even make the links. The API bit is more useful though!

Comment: Yeah wasn't sure with your question if you wanted one to make a desktop background or wanted to pull all of them via the API.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same art that you get by clicking on the magnifying glass upon mousing over a card in your Badge Progress section of your Badges / Inventory.

And *that* big image can be right-clicked and "Copy Link Address" for a downloadable image.

How to get there from a regular, non-logged in Steam account, is currently unknown to me.